# Requesting that [bard] be made a synonym of and merged into [gemini]

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging, tag-synonyms

On [February 8, 2024, Google announced that "Bard is now Gemini."](https://gemini.google.com/updates) In line with that name change, I am requesting that [bard](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bard) be made a synonym of and merged into [gemini](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gemini).